# loading json file to d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, d3.js

I've used the force.js of d3 for visualization purpose.

Following is the snippet of full js:

```
d3.json("test.json", function(json) {
  force.nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();
});
```

The test.json file is currently in same location as that of the js file. It works fine.
The files are within the 'pages' folder of my web-application. If I use the http url "http://localhost:8084/FMS/faces/pages/test.json" in place of "test.json" it works fine. 
But if I use "/Users/subashbasnet/test.json" i.e. the path of the file in place of "test.json" it doesnot work.

If I set json output to var and use in place of "test.json" it doesnot work.
Eg:

```
 var myjson = "{"nodes":[{"name":"MYriel","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}]}";
    d3.json(myjson, function(json) {
      force.nodes(json.nodes)
          .links(json.links)
          .start();
    });
```

My .jsp file has following output:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre>{"nodes":[{"name":"MYriel","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}]}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

How am I suppose to load the json within the `<pre>` tag in place of "test.json" .

Solution to either of the problem is very much awaited.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're generating the data in your JSP then you could simply have it do

```
<script>var theData = (<%= unquotedJsonData %>);</script>
```

which produces a JS object directly rather than a JSON string

```
<script>var theData = ({"nodes":[...]});</script>
```

Then you don't need to use d3's json parser, just do

```
force.nodes(theData.nodes)....
```

Comment: @SubashBasnet If this answer solved your problem, please consider _accepting_ it by clicking the green tick mark to the left.  People will be more willing to answer your future questions if they see that you will accept helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes to quote your json string

```
var myjson = '{"nodes":[{"name":"MYriel","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}]}';
```

or escape the double quotes

```
var myjson = "{\"nodes\":[{\"name\":\"MYriel\",\"group\":1},{\"name\":\"Labarre\",\"group\":2}],\"links\":[{\"source\":1,\"target\":0,\"value\":1}]}";
```

Your jsp file needs to output only the json string

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"MYriel","group":1},{"name":"Labarre","group":2}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0,"value":1}]}
```